# Date and time nearest match excel

Tags: excel

I want to find a nearest match of dates. I have an ID in Column D, I add a date to column E, and I want to find from other table a nearest match for same ID in column A.

[image: table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula in cell `F2`:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$15,MATCH(SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$15=D2,ABS($B$2:$B$15-E2)),1),IF($A$2:$A$15=D2,ABS($B$2:$B$15-E2)),0))
```

Confirm with ctl + shift + enter